# When to use '$injector' and just injector in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In the documentation for angularJS [injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector), some of the code uses `$injector`, while some code uses just `injector`.  I am confused.  What are the differences between these two, and where are the appropriate places to use them?  I also have the same question for `$scope` and `scope`.

Comment: see this http://www.egghead.io/video/NnB2NBtoeAY. It boils down to if you use injection annotations or not

Comment: Thanks! Those videos look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use `injector`, `scope`, or any other build in angularjs provider as dependency of other service you need to prefix them with `$`, as angular by convention registers all build in providers with `$` prefix, so `scope` is registered as `$scope`, `injector` as `$injector` etc.

When angular instantiates objects(using injector btw) it checks what dependencies object has (as it needs to inject them) and the way it's done is by checking variables names of constructor function of that object, so that's why it's so important to name variables correctly or you'll get error unknown provider ...

When you retrieve injector as following:

```js
var injector = angular.injector(['gaad', 'components']);
```

you don't use $ prefix, as it's normal variable and actually you can call it whatever you want ($injector included).

When you want to have injector as dependency, you need to name it as following:

```js
angular.module('app').factory('$exceptionHandler', function($injector) {
  ...
});
```

or (convention needed when you use minification of angularjs scripts):

```js
angular.module('app').factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', function(anyNameYouWant)   {
  ...
}]);
```

Similar for scope, when used in link function in directive:

```js
 link: function(scope, element, attr) {
 }
```

you don't have to call it $scope as nothing is injected here. It's only one of function parameters. You can call it whatever you want, but convention here is to use `scope` not `$scope` to differentiate cases when scope is injected and when is used as parameter.

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies the confusion.

Comment: Np, I was confused about it at first too :)